# how to generalize query with more of two dates in ArrayField(models.DateTimeField()) field?

Tags: python, django

I have a Model:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField
class MyClass(models.Model):
  some_field = ArrayField(models.DateTimeField(), default=list)
```

And have this query to filter for objects that has at least one of the date inside a range:

```
date_range_for_reminders_check = [yesterday.date(), timezone.now().date()]
MyClass.objects.filter((
  Q(some_field__0__date__range=date_range_for_reminders_check) |
  Q(some_field__1__date__range=date_range_for_reminders_check)
))
```

But this worked when every row of MyClass had only two dates in some_field, nowadays these may have more dates and need to be generalized take account diferent quantity of dates so i need something like:

```
date_range_for_reminders_check = [two_days_ago.date(), timezone.now().date()]
MyClass.objects.filter((
  Q(some_field__0__date__range=date_range_for_reminders_check) |
  Q(some_field__1__date__range=date_range_for_reminders_check) |
  Q(some_field__2__date__range=date_range_for_reminders_check) |
  ...
  Q(some_field__X__date__range=date_range_for_reminders_check) |
))
```

but without specifying indexs.

Comment: Don't use arrays in a relational database.

Comment: It is not a new model, the model is already in this way, and it could not be changed at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Using array-fields in a relational database is often a source of problems. Only in very specific cases these should be used.

You normally work with an extra model that saves a *single* timestamp and a reference to the `MyClass` that is used, so:

```
class MyClass(models.Model):
    pass


class MyClassTimestamp(models.Model):
    myclass = models.ForeignKey(MyClass, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField()
```

Then you filter with:

```
date_range_for_reminders_check = [yesterday.date(), timezone.now().date()]
MyClass.objects.filter(
    myclasstimestamp__timestamp__in=date_range_for_reminders_check
).distinct()
```

Comment: It is not a new model, the model is already in this way, and it could not be changed at the moment.

Comment: @Brahim: that doesn't matter: you can make a new one and perform a linearization through a data migration.

Comment: the migration itself is not a problem per se, but the rest of the necessary changes that it will cause to the rest of the software that are not related to what should be done now.

Comment: @Brahim: but your modeling is violating first normal form: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form this will make the database hard to maintain, scale, and efficiently query, as you found out.

Comment: Just to make it clear, I am not opposed to normalization. but it's not going to happen anytime soon.
Anyways, any changes we make to the database will take a few weeks to show up in Prod. And  I need to use the query in a script soon with the database as it is.

Anyways, thanks for your suggestions, I appreciate them. but what I really want to know is whether it's possible to perform the query I'm trying to write (with the current model structure) before trying another alternative i have in mind.

Comment: Solved. I used a query to show the highest number of dates used. Since the ability to have more than two dates is a new feat and hasn't been used yet, the script will work for now. If there were more dates, additional Q() statements would have been added.

as I mentioned before the script will fulfill its purpose for now.
I suggested normalizing the data into a new table and checking why an array was used in the first place and it will be done in a another ticket related to the field.

These changes will take time, but the script will be updated afterwards.

Thanks for your suggestions.